# How I can estimate growth of SQL Server database (Azure)?

Tags: sql-server, database, azure

For now I have database size 24MB and only 5MB data and I am trying to calculate future growth of database after release. The most obvious approach for me is to take one record size from table and multiply it to imaginary number. After searching I found several scripts but i could not get proper result.

According to this script I got the value for one record about 2.5KB that seems quit big.

```
SELECT 
    t.NAME AS TableName,
    s.Name AS SchemaName,
    p.rows AS RowCounts,
    SUM(a.total_pages) * 8 AS TotalSpaceKB, 
    CAST(ROUND(((SUM(a.total_pages) * 8) / 1024.00), 2) AS NUMERIC(36, 2)) AS TotalSpaceMB,
    SUM(a.used_pages) * 8 AS UsedSpaceKB, 
    CAST(ROUND(((SUM(a.used_pages) * 8) / 1024.00), 2) AS NUMERIC(36, 2)) AS UsedSpaceMB, 
    (SUM(a.total_pages) - SUM(a.used_pages)) * 8 AS UnusedSpaceKB,
    CAST(ROUND(((SUM(a.total_pages) - SUM(a.used_pages)) * 8) / 1024.00, 2) AS NUMERIC(36, 2)) AS UnusedSpaceMB
FROM 
    sys.tables t
INNER JOIN      
    sys.indexes i ON t.OBJECT_ID = i.object_id
INNER JOIN 
    sys.partitions p ON i.object_id = p.OBJECT_ID AND i.index_id = p.index_id
INNER JOIN 
    sys.allocation_units a ON p.partition_id = a.container_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    sys.schemas s ON t.schema_id = s.schema_id
WHERE 
    t.NAME NOT LIKE 'dt%' 
    AND t.is_ms_shipped = 0
    AND i.OBJECT_ID > 255 
GROUP BY 
    t.Name, s.Name, p.Rows
ORDER BY 
    t.Name
```

This script show me the size of each record in the table, in my case it was 77 bytes that looks more true and in the same time completely confuse me.

```
declare @table varchar(20)
declare @idcol varchar(10)
declare @sql varchar(1000)

set @table = 'Compliants'
set @idcol = 'Id'
set @sql = 'select ' + @idcol +' , (0'

select @sql = @sql + ' + isnull(datalength(' + name + '), 1)' 
    from syscolumns where id = object_id(@table)
set @sql = @sql + ') as rowsize from ' + @table + ' order by rowsize desc'

exec (@sql)
```

I need this calculation to be sure about future speeding that is impossible without estimate how database size will increase after release. Is there any technique to do so?

Comment: You could create a test database, populate it with the amount of records you expect and see what that means for the size. The record data is not the only thing that accounts for database size. Think about things like indexes and transaction logs that might add to the database size.

Comment: You are forgetting materialized views, indexes, blah blah blah. Point is, it will grow as it's needed. Can you really, accurately, estimate how often it will be used? How much data will be inserted each day? Storage is cheap these days. One thing is certain though. It can only grow to the size of the storage where the data files are hosted!

Answer (score 0):

I found solution for my question! This is a tool that calculates growth of database [SQL Server db size estimator](https://mattrandle.me/sql-server-database-size-estimator/)